# Python os.access() reads file no matter what

Tags: python

I have a script that checks a file for vulnerabilities. If the file path exists, the script then checks to see if the file can be read. However, when I set the file's permissions,  os.access() is able to read the file no matter what. In windows I have denied all permissions and in Linux, I have tried chmod 000 on the file and got the same output on both machines.Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print '[-] ' + filename + ' does not exist.'
        exit(0)
    if not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
        print '[-] ' + filename + ': access denied.'
        exit(0)

    print '[+] Reading Vulnerabilities From: ' + filename
```

Whenever I pass an incorrect file name or path, os.path.isFile() works fine, however os.access() doesn't. I'm fairly new to python as well, all help will be appreciated

UPDATED:

When I run the script I use the command:

```
python scriptName.py vuln_banners.txt
```

after I have already ran

```
chmod 000 vuln_banners.txt
```

The only output I get is:

```
'[+] Reading Vulnerabilities From: vuln_banners.txt
```

I ran

```
ls -la vuln_banners.txt
```

and got the output:

```
---------- 1 root root 397 Dec 31 22:32 vuln_banners.txt
```

Comment: Could you explicitly state what output you're expecting in each case, and what you're getting? (*"the same output on both machines"* is insufficiently precise.)

Comment: @NPE The file that is being passed is a text file with a list of server banners called vuln_banners.txt whenever I pass it with an incorrect name to test the os.path.isFile() like vuln-banners.txt for instance, I get the "file does not exist" as expected. However when I try to set the file permissions to deny then pass the correct filename (vuln_banners.txt), I would expect an "access denied" but I dont get that.

Comment: Now that's clear, thanks. I've tried to reproduce this and I cannot.

Comment: @pad Correct. But when i pass a correct file with no access rights, the os.access() will access it anyway.

Comment: Please include the output of `ls -la vuln_banners.txt` into the question as well as the command line you use to run the script, and its output.

Comment: I can’t reproduce this on Linux, but since you’re reading the file anyways, have you considered using a `try`/`except` on opening?

Comment: (I suspect there's something about the `chmod` that's going haywire. Or you're running the script as root. :-))

Comment: are you running the script from root or with root privileges ? Because root can actually read the file even if its permission is 000.

Comment: @Digisec I am running from root. Do I need to run it as a standard user? I should have probably mentioned I am kinda new to linux as well lol

Comment: Indeed I can reproduce the issue when running as root, but that's the intended behavior, root can read any file no matter the permissions.

Comment: @Bro_IDKU Normally, you should do **everything** as a standard user, unless otherwise needed.

Comment: gotcha!! Thanks guys, really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

It seems from your last comment that you are running the script as `root` which is a **no no** in Linux unless you **REALLY** know what you're doing.

**os.access()** will return **True** if you're running in root as you will have access to read the file even if its permissions are **000**.

I was able to reproduce your issue when I tried running your script under **root** privileges. Try running it under a normal user and it should behave as expected then.

Also, if the script fails, you don't want it to return a `0`, you want to return another value. The value `0` represents exiting with **no error**. Your script should look something similar to this where the return value of the exit is meaningful to you.

```
import sys
import os

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print '[-] ' + filename + ' does not exist.'
        rvalue = 1
    elif not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
        print '[-] ' + filename + ': access denied.'
        rvalue = 2
    else:
        print '[+] Reading Vulnerabilities From: ' + filenam
        rvalue = 0

exit(rvalue)
```