# Handle Error: Not a directory python

Tags: python, error-handling

I get the following error:

```
[Errno 20] Not a directory:
```

What I have tried so far:

```
for i in range(3):
    numOfData = len(dir_2[i])
    try:
        for j in range(numOfData):
            print os.listdir(os.path.join(dir_1[i], dir_2[i][j]))
    except OSError:
        print "Hello"
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: dir_2[i][j]  and dir_2[i] in different place. is that valid?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can u explain a little further?

Comment: just want to print the contents of directories. And then this loop encountered a non-directory and this error appeared. I just want to see that the error does not appear :)

Answer (score 1):

You could of course check if the directory exists before running `os.listdir()` using `os.path.isdir()`.

But that would not protect you against directory permissions, for instance (if it can be a problem). In that case, it would be tempting to use `os.access()` to see if you can read the directory except that it isn't that [reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747116/python-os-access-reads-file-no-matter-what)

So trying to read and catching the specific `OSError` exception seems correct (better ask for forgiveness than permission), maybe with a `os.path.isdir()` first to print a nicer message for the user if the directory doesn't exist at all.

And seeing your comment, I realize that you should put the `try/except` block *within* the loop so if there's an error, you can still process the next directory.

Comment: Could I add in the except for example "continue" so that it does not stop when it encounters a non-directory?